# How to avoid cross site request forgery in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, csrf

I am creating a web application, kn which when the admin logs in he is shown 2 options,

1. logout
2. check validity of token.

As soon as admin logs in, his session starts and in that session his id and token is stored, this token is valid for 17 hours and is stored in database table user_auth along with its expiry 'expired_at (datetime)' and 'id (integer)'. If admin clicks on 2nd option the token stored in session is compared with token in database and its expiry is checked. if token matches and is in expiry the admin will be shown data. For that,

**account (view)**

```
<a href=" <?php echo site_url('admin/logout') ?> ">logout</a>
<a href=" <?php echo site_url('admin/checkval') ?> ">check valididty of token</a>
```

**admin (controller)**

```
public function checkval(){

    $this->load->library('session');

    $goal = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $uid = $goal[0];
    $token = $goal[1];
    $this->load->model('loginmodel');

    $check_id = $this->loginmodel->token_valid($uid, $token);
    if($check_id === TRUE){
      $data['query'] = $this->loginmodel->get_last_ten_entries();
       $this->load->view('admin/account', $data);
       print_r($data);
      echo "valid";
    }else {
        echo "invalid";
    }


}
```

**Loginmodel (model)**

```
public function token_valid($uid, $token)
 {
    $this->db->select('expired_at');
    $this->db->from('user_auth');
    $this->db->where('id',$uid);
    $this->db->where('token',$token);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $expired_date = $query->row()->expired_at;
        $expired_date = date_create($expired_date);
     $cdate = date_create('now');
     $interval = date_diff($expired_date,$cdate);
     $hour = $interval->h;
     if($hour <= 17)
     {
       return TRUE;
     }else
     {
       return FALSE;
     }
 }
}
```

but the problem is if admin logs in in one tab in browser, and at another tab or window i open checkval() of controller ie http://localhost/ci/index.php/admin/checkval 
the data is still visible.
I want data to be shown in only tab in which admin has logged in, as soon as another tab is opened, new session should be started.

How do I do that?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Browsing a app with multiple tabs in a single browser wont effect your sessions. 
Try using another browser or use incognito mode or private mode.
You cannot start two new sessions for a same user and same app in the same browser.
And use csrf tokens provided by Codeigniter.

Comment: A "session" denotes a connection between a client and a server. No matter how many or few tabs a browser has it is exactly one client. What you ask cannot be done. Also, the question is about authentication and not cross-site request forgery.